# Drop Down List - Unreachable Code Detected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having difficulty populating a drop down list in my application. I need the `Client_Name` to appear on the drop down as opposed to the `ClientId`.

The error I receive is in the controller which underlines 'List' in green and says:

> Warning:Unreachable code detected.

I have not experienced this issue with the population of similar dropdowns.

My code in the controller is as follows:

```
//
// GET: /Trip/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        List<Vehicle> VehicleList = new List<Vehicle>();

        // the vehicle registrations 
        var VehicleQuery1 = from a in db.Vehicles 
                            orderby a.Vehicle_Reg
                            select a;

        VehicleList.AddRange(VehicleQuery1);

        ViewBag.VehicleId = new SelectList(VehicleList, "VehicleId", "Vehicle_Reg");

        ViewBag.TodaysDate = DateTime.Now;

        Trip NewTrip = new Trip();
        NewTrip.Date_Departed = DateTime.Now;
        return View(NewTrip); 

        // the client names 

        List<Client> ClientList = new List<Client>(); 

        var ClientQuery1 = from b in db.Clients
                         orderby b.Client_Name
                         select b;

        ClientList.AddRange(ClientQuery1);
        ViewBag.ClientId = new SelectList(ClientList, "ClientId", "Client_Name");

        return View();

    }
```

I have made changes the changes to create view as well and the code is as follows:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("ClientId", "Please Select"); 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CleintId)
</div>
```

Comment: Is that the entire controller action?

Comment: The controller has an additional dropdown code that works and this that is not working. The working dropdown code is: `List<Vehicle> VehicleList = new List<Vehicle>();

            // the vehicle registrations 
            var VehicleQuery1 = from a in db.Vehicles 
                                orderby a.Vehicle_Reg
                                select a;

            VehicleList.AddRange(VehicleQuery1);

            ViewBag.VehicleId = new SelectList(VehicleList, "VehicleId", "Vehicle_Reg");`

Comment: I think you are not using the right extension of Html.DropDownList().

Comment: Please post the whole controller action, formatted, in your question, instead of just posting arbitrarily selected snippets that don't indicate the actual problem.

Comment: `<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("VehicleId", "Please Select")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VehicleId)
        </div>`  That is used for the the VehicleList and that works. The ClientList is the problem.

Comment: My apologies. Its the first time I am using this form of programming assistance.

Comment: You are returning from your controller function before you initialize your client list.

Comment: You have a `return View(NewTrip);` in the middle of your action. After the return, the method is finished, every code after it is not executed. I can't propose an alternative here, because it is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve with your construct.

Comment: Thank you Daniel and Pawel. It now works as required. Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @NabeelaSeedat I removed tag mvc. First, MVC is design pattern and not directly related to asp.net mvc. Secondly, even if you used asp.net mvc tag, I'd still remove it, because this question has nothing to do with it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error, but a suggestion that you should examine your code and
either remove (comment out) the unreachable code or change your code above 
somehow to make the code reachable.

```
 ...
    Trip NewTrip = new Trip();
    NewTrip.Date_Departed = DateTime.Now;
    return View(NewTrip); // <- your method will always return here, no code below will ever execute 

    // These code below is unreachable: it will never be executed.
    // So the compiler advise (via warning) you either to delete (or comment out) the code below
    // or change return View(NewTrip) line

    // the client names 

    List<Client> ClientList = new List<Client>(); 

    var ClientQuery1 = from b in db.Clients
                     orderby b.Client_Name
                     select b;

    ClientList.AddRange(ClientQuery1);
    ViewBag.ClientId = new SelectList(ClientList, "ClientId", "Client_Name");

    return View();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all warnings are not errors.

Back to the warning which is quite descriptive. You have some code that will never execute (i.e. [*unreachable code*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code)). To detect what's preventing it from execution always look at the statement before the underlined statement (statement warning is referring to, in a case you use IDE that does not underline warnings).

In this case, you'll see the problem is that you use `return` without any condition, that means nothing after `return` will be executed.

> Thank you Daniel and Pawel. It now works as required. Don't know how I missed that.

If you *always* keep `return` at the end of the method you'll almost never make this mistake. And you can and should be keeping `return` at the end unless it's necessary to return because of some condition.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning twice! After the first return the following code will be not executed. The compiler warns you.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot return values twice to your actionresult, your return must be placed at the end.